# How do you encrypt an image using CTR encryption?

Tags: python, encryption, aes

Good afternoon, I am trying to write a program to read a .bmp file and encrypt it using the given initial value using  and the one-time pad.

The first 36 bytes form the header of the image and are not encrypted, but just copied to the new file

The image data beginning at 0x36 to the end are grouped into four-byte words and each word is encrypted using .

To avoid changing the size of the image, do not include 0= in the encrypted image.

As of now, this is what I have:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from Crypto.Util import Counter

filename = "Image11.bmp"
filename_out = "Image11Encrypted.bmp"
key = 0xe0984dd3
bkey = key.to_bytes(32, 'big')
cipher = AES.new(bkey, AES.MODE_CTR, initial_value= 0xff128eff)

def encrypt(filename, filename_out, key):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        clear = f.read()
    clear_trimmed = clear[64:-2]
    ciphertext = clear_trimmed
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(clear_trimmed, 16))
    ciphertext = clear[0:64] + ciphertext + clear[-2:]
    with open(filename_out, "wb") as f:
        f.write(ciphertext)

encrypt(filename, filename_out, key)
print("Encrypted using AES in CTR mode and saved to \"" + filename_out + "\"")
```

However, I keep running into this Error:

[image: Error].

Any help would be great, not sure where to go from here

Comment: Code and errors should be posted here as text, never images

Comment: The docs suggest that `counter` should be of type `Crypto.Util.Counter`, not a number (with value 0xff128eff).

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of the CTR mode with PyCryptodome is described [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ctr-mode). There are two ways to specify the counter block: By setting a nonce (parameter `nonce`) and a start value (parameter `initial_value`). If no nonce is specified, a random nonce of half the block size is generated implicitly.

The other way is to define a [counter block object](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-counter-module) (parameter `counter`), which can be used to specify the components of the counter block in detail (prefix, counter, suffix).

If only the start value is to be specified, the parameter `initial_value` must be used instead of `counter`:

```python
cipher = AES.new(bkey, AES.MODE_CTR, initial_value=0xff128eff)
```

As mentioned above, this implicitly creates a random nonce with half the block size, which can be determined with `cipher.nonce`.

Please note: The code lacks the determination of the 16 byte IV, which is needed for decryption. The IV consists of nonce and counter and is usually placed on byte level before the ciphertext.
Furthermore, according to the question the first 36 bytes should not be encrypted, a little later it is stated that the data starts at 0x36 (=54) and in the code 64 is used as the beginning of the data. This seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you so much this fixes the initial problem. However, I run into another issue where AES is not defined. Not sure how it is not defined when it is already been imported. I edited the photo to match the new error that popped up

Comment: @MattStrayer - First, please roll back your last change and display the _original_ error message again (preferably as text and not as a screenshot / image), otherwise subsequent readers will not be able to understand the problem. Then either ask a new question or, if there is a reference to the current question, post the new information following the old question with a note (_Update_ or _Edit_). Thank you.

Comment: @MattStrayer - Kindly add information about your environment: OS, IDE, and especially which versions of Python and PyCryptodome you use.